# How to keep entered text in edittext field?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that require user to enter name, email, date and etc in Main_Activity.xml. Then, the user will click submit. The entered data will be displayed in confirm.xml. In confirm.xml, user need to verify entered data and if the want to edit entered data, they will click back button to edit data again. I tried to do that but once I click back button, all the data I entered in editText field disappeared. I want to keep the data I entered in MainActivity.xml's editText field, so I can change only some field that need to be edited. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: Did you clear data?

Comment: dont use keyword like `finish()` in mainactivity

Comment: Use shared preferences to store/fetch the data, clear it once you confirm.

Comment: @Shree thank you for suggestion. I've just read about share preferences. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` function and use the savedInstanceState to save the various data that you want to get back during the `onCreate(Bundle instanceState)` or `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle instanceState)`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putString("TextFieldX", "Data To Retrieve");
}
```

And get it back:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  //get back value
  String value = savedInstanceState.getString("TextFieldX");
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

For longer lived persistance of your data, you would write it to [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the activity where you entered data is destroyed. How do you open the new confirmation activity? That's the part of the code that probably contains the error.

If you call `finish()` when you open the new activity then activity will be destroyed and data kept in `EditText` cleared.

To open a new activity and preserve data of the current one you just need to call `startActivity(...)` without `finish()`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfirmationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Anyway, the activity can be destroyed by android to free up memory when needed. That happens when you open another application that needs memory but memory is used by your application, so the system destroys your activities and it's up to you to save data on disk by using `Bundles` and restoring them.

I suggest you to read this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all your information to String's like private String Name;
 write/set this Name when user enter's the Name and use it again like as follows:

```
if(name != null && !name.toString().isEmpty()) {
 set name String on your editText widget.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference object to save value of edittext value in user's phone. When code execute second time, you just check about variable in shared preference. If variable is not null, fetch value from it and set that string using **setText()** method.